# Magento models: how to get data from an array, rather than a database?

Tags: model, magento, adapter

Typically, Magento's models are "backed" by a MySQL database--this is where the data comes from, and is persisted to.  How can I get the data from a standard PHP array?  Is there some sample code available anywhere?  (I'm especially interested in the "reading" aspect at the moment, but it would be useful to know how to "write" too.)

Answer (score 1):

if you just track a model save through and see it calls the save of its resource model

```
$this->_getResource()->beginTransaction();
    $dataCommited = false;
    try {
        $this->_beforeSave();
        if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
            $this->_getResource()->save($this);
            $this->_afterSave();
```

this resource has the method

```
  $this->_getWriteAdapter();
```

from which you can call plenty of sql methods

Answer (score 0):

Internally magento stores all the data in a local `_data` variable in each object. You could easily add your data to that (fx. using the `addData` method).